# How to consume (*.asmx) web service in Sql server 2008

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asmx

I want to consume a C# web service inside a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure. Main concept behind that it we want to run scheduler of SQL Server (by using SQL Server agent) every 30 minutes, but logic is written in a C# class.

How to run web service in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: If its in c# why dont you convert it into .net Stored proc which can be deployed on the SQL server box. Or may be you can have a .net stored proc which access the web service so the logic remains in the web service and you use c# code to access it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just write a SQL-CLR stored procedure in C# that gets called by the Agent?

Comment: @Nilesh means .Net Clr procedure ? or any els ?

Comment: Yes .Net Clr procedure. Not sure if it fits in your project preferences.

Comment: frnds Is it possible through SSIS Package ?